# Submit subscription request to PayPal from PHP form

Tags: php, paypal

The documentation is very vague everywhere on this issue, and so are the questions online (including this site): 
I have a form that the user must fill out with a few fields. For example, a username and password. Then, they have to purchase something through PayPal. I've created a business account. When the user submits my form it simply queries and adds them to a local database through the PHP at the present. I want to first verify payment through PayPal and then add them to the database. I've also tried adding them to the database with a "paid=0" by default and then trying to get PayPal to send me a success token or something that I can then flip the value to 1, but I'm at a loss for where to start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paypal Payment Standard: Callback URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039861/paypal-payment-standard-callback-url)

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/

Comment: @DarkBee both links in the answer are dead, for one. Two, I already looked at it. I don't understand since there are many conflicting examples.

Comment: @MarvinFischer That is not an answer to my problem, afaik that does NOT support subscription plans.

Comment: Then have a look at the new guides, [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#ipn-overview) and [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/#)

Comment: Viewed those, thanks anyway. It's not specific enough for my needs and I find them lacking in information and real world examples with custom forms even after extensive research.

Comment: @GMR516 https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/ I expected some own search before you ask those questions

Comment: Before you assume, you should take a few seconds and read up a comment or two and realize that I did, in fact, research. I came to Stack Overflow to find help because I figured there would be experts here who could tell me what I was missing. Thanks for attempting to help by posting links to the documentation that I quoted was vague and didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i advice you to use [PHP Paypal offical SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) with [offical subscription's example](https://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/#billing).

It is be a good idea to store transaction before any Paypal Request, because you can track errors.

Use a "**status**" field to store transaction status. after that you can do Paypal Payment.
After,  you change the status depending on Paypal response.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So what's your real problem ?

Comment: I don't understand how to simply verify a transaction as "OK" and send it to my site. Should I use the REST api, or the IPN thing? Do I just have a .php sitting serverside verifying transactions, and how do I connect that to the IPN response or whatever they send me?

Comment: In my opinion IPN is the good way. i've found php IPN [example](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php)
**EDIT**: [To use IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/#using-ipn-in-your-checkout-flow)

Comment: I have that sitting on my server right now, but I'm not sure what to do with it. Does that capture all payment requests? More importantly, does it handle subscriptions?

Comment: This is list of  [Paypal webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/event-names/#billing-plans-and-agreements).
As you can see there is `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED`,`BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.SUSPENDED`. to use this you have to configure it in your **Paypal account**. After, you've to create a script (or a route) where Paypal will be able to send a request for each hooks configured

Comment: Thank you, I will check that out.

Comment: @GMR516 glad to help you